# Need to recover BIOS settings from bricked eee

Tags: bios, system-restore

I'm new in the computer world and I just bricked my first laptop. I tried to power on the laptop without a CMOS battery. Now only the power and WiFi lights are on. No monitor, nothing.

Comment: After you started the laptop without the CMOS battery, you left it turned on, then placed the battery back in right?  Have you read the manual on how to reset your BIOS on this device?  Its also possible that the BIOS cannot be recovered you might have to accept that fact.

Comment: No, I didn't. I turned it off. Dumb move I know

Comment: You need to reset the BIOS the correct way.  Try my suggestion.  To be clear you leave it turned on for awhile, then shut it down, then replace the battery.  Putting the CMOS battery while the laptop is turned on WILL fry the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Something does not make sense here.

1 you are new to computerized world, so you say.

2 But you know how to take out the CMOS battery ?

3 Why in the world would you do that?

Your BIOS information is gone (since it uses the CMOS battery to stay alive).

There is no way to replace your BIOS information on the ROM chip without running computer.

Since you know how to take out the CMOS battery, you might be able to repair.

If the ROM BIOS chip for your computer is in a socket rather than soldered to the motherboard, you can replace it with an identical chip to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm not that new. I am certified a+, but I just got it. So I'm still considered a noob. I think I can repair it but I need a more experienced tech to point me n the right direction

Comment: @coreym. - You only need to look at the manual to understand how to recover the BIOS.

Comment: Manual doesn't cover this part. I know how to recover the bios.the computer doesn't POST.

Comment: @Benalmadena--I took out the battery because it was dead and needed to b replaced. Correct me if I'm wrong, but when the battery dies u replace it right? That's why I did it

Comment: corey, yes you're right.. you do replace the battery when the battery dies. And your settings just reset it's no big deal. I'm not sure about what banal is writing